# How to resolve error in fpdf when trying to store pdf in a directory?

Tags: php, fpdf

> > Error Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Incorrect output destination: pdf/602136a2c8b9f.pdf in C:.... Stack trace: #0 C:..... FPDF->Error('Incorrect outpu...') #1 C:\x...FPDF->Output('pdf/602136a2c8b...')

> > > This error is displayed when I use the latest version of FPDF. If I use an older one it does work. However, other issues arise.

> > > How can I resolve this issue.

require('fpdf182/fpdf.php');

```
$po='name';
$dir='pdf/';
$filename= $po.'.pdf';
$pdf ->Output($dir.$filename);
```

Comment: *"How can I resolve this issue"* Maybe by checking [the documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm)?

Answer (score 1):

After I read the documentation, I found the solution was adding 'F' in
$pdf ->Output('F',$dir.$filename);